# AspNetCore WebApi ODataController Cannot Deserialize JSON Payload

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I am having an trouble getting my V4 ODataController to deserialize a JSON payload.  I have created a sample project in github to illustrate my exact issue:

https://github.com/valainisgt/BadODataDeserialization

When the data submitted to the '/odata/models' endpoint using a content-type of application/json, the model is not populated.  Using the exact same data keys and values but this time as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the model is populated.

What am I missing here?

Edit:

Here is what my payload looks like:

```
{ 'ModelId': 0, 'Name': "John Doe" }
```

This is an asp.net core application targeting .NET 462.

As such I am using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.* packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the data submitted to the '/odata/models' endpoint using a content-type of application/json, the model is not populated. Using the exact same data keys and values but this time as application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the model is populated.

1. If you would like to receive a content-type of `application/json` , you need to decorate your Model with a `[FromBody]`

   ```
   public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Model m)
   ```

Test case :

```
POST http://localhost:50317/odata/models HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{
    ModelId:11,
    Name:"hello"
}
```

2. If you want to receive a content-type of `x-www-form-urlencoded` , you should add a `[Bind()]` :

   ```
   public IActionResult Post([Bind("ModelId,Name")]Model m)
   ```

Test Case :

```
POST http://localhost:50317/odata/models HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

ModelId=11&Name=hello
```

However , there's no built-in modelbinder that will bind both data types . If you do want to do that , consider the following approach :

1. write two action methods and route according to different headers
2. custom a modelbinder

For more information , refer docs [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2018/07/03/asp-net-core-odata-now-available/)

Comment: Decorating my action parameter with the FromBodyAttribute does not accomplish the task.  When using the FromBodyAttribute the model is actually null instead of a default instance!

Comment: @GregValainis Do you mean that the project on Github won't work if you decorate it with a [FromBody] attribute and send a application/json payload ?

Comment: correct.  I believe there is a bug in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData package.  I have opened an issue with the project on github.  [https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1619](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1619)

Comment: I must be going crazy because I know i had tried decorating my action parameter with the 'FromBodyAttribute' and did not get the expected result.  However that no longer seems to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

FromBodyAttribute in the action method signature if you are doing HttpPost to your endpoint.

For example,

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod([FromBody] MyPayload payload)
```

{ .... *your code* }